# Making media element circular in silverlight

Tags: c#, silverlight, xaml, mediaelement

I want to make a video MediaElement into a circular shape, but i cannot find a way to do it?
Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming you want to crop the video (not distort it), it sounds like you can either:

- Apply an [Opacity Mask](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms743320.aspx) to the MediaElement
- Use a [VideoBrush](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc189009%28VS.95%29.aspx) (Silverlight only) as the fill for the circular shape

Answer (score 0):

Well you have to create a MASK of Rectangle with Circle as MASK inside Rectangle, which you can put it on the top of your Media Element. So rectangular part will be covered by Rectangle's opaq part and only circular transparent part will be visible.

Answer (score 0):

The right and easy way is...

EllipseGeometry and MediaElement/UIElement Clip Property

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.uielement.clip.aspx